# Privilege and Repository windows not showing in Eclipse Sap hana studio?

Tags: java, eclipse, hana, eclipse-2019-09, sap-cloud-connector

I am working on Eclipse sap hana and by mistake i closed Privilege and Repository tab in Eclipse and i am not able to open it again.

Previously it was looking like this:

[image]

But after closing the tabs it looks like the below image and i don't know how to open these table again. Please help if you have any idea about this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

Go to `Window` => `Show View`:

[image: Go to window - show view]

and select `Repositories` and click `Open`:

[image: select Repository and click open]